# Convert multiple Shapefiles in Raster in R(and then plot it)

Tags: raster, r, coordinate-system

I'm trying to convert several shapefiles in rasters at the same time. I already was able to read the shapefiles by doing this:

```
library(maptools)

shps <- dir(getwd(), "*.shp")
for (shp in shps) assign(shp, readShapePoly(shp))
for(j in 1:245)
{
New<-readShapePoly(shps[j])     
}
```

But now, I don't know how to convert these to raster and then plotting it. I tried the commands on this page, but I only obtain errors

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short example using Tanzanian administrative data obtained from [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata). I am using `lapply` to loop through all layers, `readOGR` from the `rgdal`package to import the single shapefiles and `rasterize` from the `raster` package to perform the conversion. Make sure to set up a template, otherwise you won't be able to convert the shapefiles.

```
# Required packages
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

# Loop through single layers
adm <- lapply(c("TZA_adm0", "TZA_adm1", "TZA_adm2", "TZA_adm3"), function(i) {
  # Import shapefile
  shp <- readOGR("data", i)
  # Create raster template
  template <- raster(ext = extent(shp), crs = projection(shp))
  # Rasterize shapefile
  rst <- rasterize(shp, template, field = "Shape_Area")
})
```

Don't forget to adjust the `field` argument in the `rasterize` function to your personal needs. Here's what we end up with (well, the plot doesn't really make sense, but the end justifies the means, right? ;-)).

```
plot(adm[[2]], xlab = "lon", ylab = "lat", main = "Shape_Area_adm1")
```

[image: Level 2 administrative boundaries of Tanzania]

Hope this helps,
Cheers!